# How to create terraform backend.tf file from python before execution to eliminiate interpolation state file issue

Tags: python, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Actually we bulit webapp from there we are passing variables to the terraform by

like below

```
terraform apply -input=false -auto-approve -var ami="%ami%" -var region="%region%" -var icount="%count%" -var type="%instance_type%"
```

Actually the problem here was backend does not support variables i need to pass there values also form app.

TO resolve this I find some solution like we need to create backend.tf before execution.

But I am unable to get the idea how to do it if anyone having any exmaples regarding this please help me.

Thanks in advance..

I need to create backend.tf file from python by using below variables.

And need to replace key="${profile}/tfstate

for each profile the profile need to replace

i am thinking of using git repo by using git we create files and pull the values and again commit and execute

Please help me with some examples and ideas.

Code is like below:

My main.tf like below

```
terraform {
    backend “s3” {
        bucket = “terraform-007”
        key = “key”
        region = “ap-south-1”
        profile=“venu”
    }
} 

provider “aws” {
    profile = “ var.awsprofile"
    region="{var.aws_region}”
}

resource “aws_instance” “VM” {
    count = var.icount
    ami = var.ami
    instance_type = var.type
    tags = {
        Environment = “${var.env_indicator}”
    }
}
```

vars.tf like

```
variable “aws_profile” {
    default = “default”
    description = “AWS profile name, as set in ~/.aws/credentials”
}

variable “aws_region” {
    type = “string”
    default = “ap-south-1”
    description = “AWS region in which to create resources”
}

variable “env_indicator” {
    type = “string”
    default = “dev”
    description = “What environment are we in?”
}

variable “icount” {
    default = 1
}

variable “ami” {
    default =“ami-54d2a63b”
}

variable “bucket” {
    default=“terraform-002”
}

variable “type” {
    default=“t2.micro”
}
```

output.tf like:

```
output “ec2_public_ip” {    
    value = ["${aws_instance.VM.*.public_ip}"]    
}

output “ec2_private_ip” {
    value = ["${aws_instance.VM.*.private_ip}"]
}
```

Actually the problem here was backend does not support variables i need to pass there values also form app.

TO resolve this I find some solution like we need to create backend.tf before execution.

But I am unable to get the idea how to do it if anyone having any exmaples regarding this please help me.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Since the configuration for the backend cannot use interpolation, we have used a configuration by convention approach.

1. The terraform for all of our state collections (microservices and other infrastructure) use the same S3 bucket for state storage and the same DynamoDB table for locking.
2. When executing terraform, we use the same IAM role (a dedicated terraform only user).
3. We define the key for the state via convention, so that it does not need to be generated.

   ```
   key = "platform/services/{name-of-service}/terraform.tfstate"
   ```

I would avoid a process that results in changes to the infrastructure code as it is being deployed to ensure maximum understand-ability by the engineers reading/maintaining the code.

EDIT: Adding key examples

For the user service:

```
key = "platform/services/users/terraform.tfstate"
```

For the search service:

```
key = "platform/services/search/terraform.tfstate"
```

For the product service:

```
key = "platform/services/products/terraform.tfstate"
```

Comment: thanks for the comment .key = "platform/services/{name-of-service}/terraform.tfstate" is {name of service is static or dynamic} here

Comment: We have a separate terraform file for deploying each service, so {name-of-service} would be specific to the service that file is deploying.